# What are some toy models for the stable homotopy groups of spheres?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

The graded ring $\pi_\ast^s$ of stable homotopy groups of spheres is a horrible ring. It is non-Noetherian, and nilpotent torsion outside of degree zero.

**Question:** What are some "toy models" for the ring $\pi_\ast^s$?

By this, I mean examples which illustrate particular pathologies of this ring. For example, if $k$ is a field, then the ring of dual numbers $k[x]/x^2$ exhibits the pathology of being non-reduced. But that barely scratches the surface of the bad properties that $\pi_\ast^s$ has.

Comment: We don't know so many things about this ring.  For example, it has not been proved that one can find elements $x_1, x_2, \dots$ in positive degree such that the product of the first $n$ of these is nonzero for all $n$.  The rings John Palmieri mentions have this property, but maybe our ring doesn't.

Answer (score 26):

My favorite warmup example to the stable homotopy groups of spheres is the following differential graded algebra.

---

Let $A$ have the underlying ring
$$
\Bbb Z[y] \otimes \Lambda[x],
$$
a ring with a polynomial generator $y$ and an exterior generator $x$. Give these the gradings $|x| = 1$ and $|y| = 2$, making it graded-commutative; give it differential $d(x) = 0$ and $d(y) = x$. Then $d(y^k) = k y^{k-1} x$ and $d(y^k x) = 0$ by the Leibniz rule.

The homology groups satisfy
$$
H_k(A) = \begin{cases}
\Bbb Z&\text{if }k = 0,\\
\Bbb Z/n&\text{if }k = 2n-1,\text{ generated by }y^{n-1} x\\
0&\text{otherwise.}\\
\end{cases}
$$

---

Here are some parallels with the stable homotopy groups of spheres.

**Finiteness**. The bottom group is $\Bbb Z$ and all the higher groups are torsion.

**Nilpotence**. All elements in positive degree are nilpotent. (For a silly reason: if $\alpha$ is any element in positive degree, then $\alpha^2$ is in positive even degree and so it is zero.)

**Periodicity**. The homology groups exhibit image-of-$J$-esque behavior. If we have a $p$-torsion element $\alpha$ in degree $k$, then we tend to have another $p$-torsion element "$y^p \alpha$" in degree $k+2p$. If we have a $p^2$-torsion element $\beta$ in degree $k$, then we tend to have another $p^2$-torsion element "$y^{p^2} \beta$" in degree $k + 2p^2$. (And so on.) This happens despite the fact that $y$ is not an element in the ring $H_* A$ and so multiplication by it is not a well-defined operation.

**Periodic self-maps**. Just as with the stable homotopy groups of spheres, we can explain periodicity by looking at $A$-modules. For any $n$ we have a differential graded module $A/p^n$ fitting into an exact triangle $A \to A \to A/p^n$ ($A$ was flat, and so we can represent this by the levelwise quotient). This module *does* have a self-map $y^{p^n}: A/p^n \to A/p^n$ inducing the periodicity we see on homology of *any* $A$-module.

**Toda brackets**. We can still correspondingly interpret these periodicity operators as brackets. If $\alpha$ is $p^n$-torsion, then there is a Massey product
$$
\langle y^{p^n - 1} x, p^n, \alpha\rangle
$$
in degree $|\alpha| + 2p^n$. This also implements this periodicity.

**Analogues of chromatic spectra**. There is an $A$-algebra $B = \Bbb Z[y]$ -- the quotient by $x$ -- and a $B$-algebra $K = \Bbb Z/p[y^{\pm 1}]$. These play similar roles to the Brown-Peterson spectrum $BP$ and a Morava $K$-theory $K(n)$ in detecting these periodic phenomena. The analogue of the Adams-Novikov spectral sequence is a long exact sequence
$$
\dots \to H_{*-1} (B \otimes^{\Bbb L}_A M) \to H_*(M) \to H_*(B \otimes^{\Bbb L}_A M) \to \dots
$$
which comes from the short exact sequence $0 \to (x) \to A \to A/(x) \to 0$, equivalent to $0 \to \Sigma B \to A \to B \to 0$.

**Nilpotence theorem**. If $R$ is an $A$-algebra, then the kernel of the map $H_* R \to H_*(B \otimes^{\Bbb L}_A R)$ consists of nilpotent elements. (All elements in the kernel of $H_* R \to H_*(B \otimes_A^{\Bbb L} R)$ are, in fact, representable by multiples of $x$, and so they square to zero.)

**Telescopic localization**. We can localize with respect to $K$. Localization with respect to $K$ is represented by the telescopic localization $\lim_n (y^{-1} A/p^n)$. (The category of $K$-local modules even has extra elements in its Picard group!)

Et cetera.

---

If nothing else, one of the things that this example illustrates is that there can be examples which are quite regular (the ring $A$ is simple) but whose visible structure (the ring $H_* A$) is pathological. The pathological appearance is partly because there is subtext (the generator $y$) which is not immediately visible to us and has to be detected in other ways.

Answer (score 15):

You could say that I've made a living out of looking at the stable module category of a finite group (or rather its slight enlargement, the homotopy category of complexes of injective modules, $\mathsf{KInj}(kG)$) as a toy model for the stable homotopy category, which makes $H^*(G,k)$ the analogue of the stable homotopy ring. The Balmer spectrum is a bit more complicated than that of stable homotopy theory, but the fact that $H^*(G,k)$ is Noetherian simplifies a lot of things. Please look at my work with Carlson and Rickard, with Iyengar and Krause, and with Greenlees, for various aspects of this.

Answer (score 8):

As Dave Benson says, the Noetherian condition simplifies a lot of things. The derived category of a commutative ring satisfies many of the properties of the stable homotopy category. The derived category of, say, $k[x]/(x^2)$ is boring from the point of view of stable homotopy category, but the derived category of $k[x_1, x_2, x_3, ...]/(x_i^2)$ is more interesting and complicated. You can look at my paper "The Bousfield lattice for truncated polynomial algebras" with Bill Dwyer: we looked at it hoping to see of the complications that arise when you pass to the non-Noetherian setting. Amnon Neeman looked at a similar derived category in his paper "Oddball Bousfield classes."

tl;dr: try $k[x_1, x_2, x_3, ...]/(x_i^2)$, or as Neeman did, $k[x_2, x_3, x_4, ...]/(x_i^i)$ for toy examples.